Parametrization of the boundary of a manifold from paramterization of the manifold
Suppose we have some smooth manifold with boundary $M$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$, an open set $G \subset {\mathbb R}^k$, where $k$ is the dimension of the manifold, and a smooth map $F: \bar{G} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$ s.t. $M = F(\bar{G})$ and $F$ is injective only on G (but not $\bar{G}$). Under what conditions can we ensure that $\partial M = F(\partial G)$? This is clearly not always true, consider, for example, Möbius band and its parametrization that can be found on Wikipedia.

The word "bijective" is meaningful only if the range is prescribed. What do you assume about $F(G)$?

@MoisheKohan, a poor choice of words from my side. I do not place any assumptions on $F(G)$. I have edited my post and changed “bijective” to “injective”

Also, "open set" is undefined until you state "open subset of..."

@MoisheKohan, a very good point. I have edited the post to include that $G$ is a subset of ${\mathbb R}^k$ (with the standard topology)
